# Cordova - Best approach to save images in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, cordova, firebase

I'm building a Cordova App that connects to a NodeJS Api. In the middle I have added Firebase to help me out with Authentication.

Now I want to store user's images into some server. What would it be the best approach?

a) Firebase storage: User will send image file to Firebase Storage and my nodeJS server will fetch that image's link and stores into Mondodb.

b) Send the image directly to Nodejs and it will save it somewhere else (e.g Google cloud, Azure)

What do you think?

Comment: Just use a CDN as you should do with any website or application that has to serve images over time.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."